# Extract the exact value used in a PACT (when the match is done via a regexp as value not initially known))

Tags: ruby, pact, pact-ruby

I have a ruby pact mock service provider that captures my request. I would like to extract the exact value provided in the request (which was matched by a Pact.term / Pact.like), to do further processing with that value once the request has been answered by the pact service provider.

An example: a password reset functionality. Code makes an API call to a mailing service, providing the password reset link as parameter. Pact captures the request and mocks it successfully, validating the data. I pass the reset_link as one of the parameters (a Json body). This gets match in a Pact.term. All good. But I also want to recover the exact value that was used in the request (say reset_link: 'http://sample.com/reset-password?key=12345'), so I can make a subsequent request and check that exact link does indeed allow a successful password reset.

Now, if I was sending email directly, it is easy to do, I can just parse Mail::TestMailer.deliveries.last

How can I do this?

I've gone through the code, even creating a Pact::SomethingLike subclass wouldn't work, as the comparison method is a lovely functional programming module, not a method in the class.

Is there a before / after hook, or a way to grab the whole web request?

PS: I'm aware this is typically tested by the underlying library I use. The library sanctioned way of adjusting functionality is to override certain methods, I need to re-test the whole functionality.

PPS: this is not rails but roda.

Thanks
André

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Pact Ruby supports this exact requirement, however digging into *why* you're doing this, I'd suggest it's a bad idea.

This is a functional test, something that Pact consciously makes difficult to support. See https://docs.pact.io/best_practices/contract_tests_not_functional_tests.html for more details as to why. There are better tools for the job for these sorts of tests, and they don't belong in the consumer code base (they absolutely *do* belong in the Providers' test suite).

Pact is a *contract testing* tool, and as such is only interested in isolated request/response contracts, not chained ones as per functional tests.